# Why is Windows Azure's Git Deploy regularly unable to access my repository?

Tags: git, azure, deployment, github

> View Log
>
> Fetching changes.
>
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/bigfont/BigFont/': Failed
>   connect to github.com:443; No error
>
> D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe fetch external --progress

This message happens about 20 times a day while I deploy changes to our website. Why does it happen? How do we fix it? The problem seems to arise and the resolve itself randomly.

Comment: We're also getting this :(

Comment: We ended up using SSH instead of HTTP and that's starting to get us some success now.